# Unexpected stack smashing

Tags: c

I have written a compressor(program) in c which is working perfectly for files except one which is constantly giving me stack smash error and i cant determine why.

**GDB error**

```
Breakpoint 1, load (wordlist=0x7fffffffd760, file=0x7fffffffe444 "Doxyfile", size=0x7fffffffdf94, uniqueWord=0x7fffffffdf98) at hashstruct.c:286
286   fclose(fp);
(gdb) n
288   return 0;
(gdb) n
289 }
(gdb) n
*** stack smashing detected ***: /home/sujit/c/cproject/util terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7ffff7828f47]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x0)[0x7ffff7828f10]
/home/sujit/c/cproject/util[0x403486]
/home/sujit/c/cproject/util[0x40218f]
/home/sujit/c/cproject/util[0x400f60]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7ffff773f76d]
/home/sujit/c/cproject/util[0x400a69]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00405000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 1574093                            /home/sujit  /c/cproject/util
00604000-00605000 r--p 00004000 08:06 1574093                            /home/sujit/c/cproject/util
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 08:06 1574093                            /home/sujit/c/cproject/util
00606000-01014000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff7508000-7ffff751d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 134958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff751d000-7ffff771c000 ---p 00015000 08:06 134958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff771c000-7ffff771d000 r--p 00014000 08:06 134958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff771d000-7ffff771e000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 134958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff771e000-7ffff78d3000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff78d3000-7ffff7ad3000 ---p 001b5000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7ad3000-7ffff7ad7000 r--p 001b5000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7ad7000-7ffff7ad9000 rw-p 001b9000 08:06 131977                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7ffff7ad9000-7ffff7ade000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ade000-7ffff7bd9000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 141974                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7bd9000-7ffff7dd8000 ---p 000fb000 08:06 141974                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7dd8000-7ffff7dd9000 r--p 000fa000 08:06 141974                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7dd9000-7ffff7dda000 rw-p 000fb000 08:06 141974                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7ffff7dda000-7ffff7dfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 141975                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7fda000-7ffff7fdd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff7000-7ffff7ffb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00022000 08:06 141975                     /lib/x86_64- linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 141975                     /lib/x86_64-linux-g gnu/ld-2.15.so
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7754425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>)
at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

The code of load function is:

```
int
load (hashstruct * wordlist, char *file, int *size, int *uniqueWord)
{
  // initialising wordlist
  hashstruct_deafult_value (wordlist, NULL, (char) 0);
  // declaring word
  char word[LENGTH];
  // opening the file
  FILE *fp = fopen (file, "r");
  // proceding if the file is succesfully opened
  if (fp != NULL)
    {
      while (getWord (fp, word) != EOF) //fscanf(fp,"%s",word) != EOF)
        {
          hashstruct *back;
          int returnValue = hash_put (wordlist, word, uniqueWord, &back);
          if (returnValue != 0)
            return returnValue;
          sizeadd (size);
        }
    }
  else
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "unable to open file");
      return -1;
    }
  fclose (fp);
  return 0;
}


int getWord(FILE* inptr, char word[])
{
 int noofchar = 0;
 int c = 0;
 if ( feof(inptr) )
 {
return EOF;
 }
else
 {

  while ( (c = getc(inptr)) != EOF && c != ' ' )
{
    if ( !(c > 0 && c < 256) )
        fprintf(stderr,"\nnot in char range"); 
    if (noofchar >= LENGTH)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nbuffer memory overflow in getWord");
        break;
    }
            word[noofchar++] = (char)c;
}

  word[noofchar]='\0';
  return noofchar;
  }
  }
```

Comment: `(char)0);` did you mean: `(char*)0);` ? (or just: `NULL` which is simpler ?)

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be here in this function -- at some point, you've overwritten the "what to do when the program ends" part of the program, and now that your program has ended, the error is discovered.

Comment: its (char)0 ie NULL character

Comment: If `getWord` does the same as `fscanf(fp,"%s",word)` (as the comment on that line might imply) make sure it can never read more than `LENGTH` characters (including null-terminator) into `word` (i.e. when using the `scanf`-family use the length parameter for the `%s` specifier)

Comment: `while ( getWord(fp,word) != EOF )` This looks dangerous. Does `getWord()` know that the size of the buffer is `LENGTH`, or does it happily overflows with words larger than `LENGTH` characters?

Comment: The name `hashstruct_deafult_value` should probably use 'default' in place of 'deafult'.  The test for `if ( !(c > 0 && c < 256) )
        fprintf(stderr,"\nnot in char range");` is redundant unless `CHAR_BIT > 8`; the values returned by `getc()` are positive except for EOF.  The error message illustrates a common bad practice; you should include the newline at the end of the string, not the beginning, especially on Unix systems. For the rest, the problem is still not in the code shown but somewhere else. You're running on Linux; use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) and see whether it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but look at the following pieces of code:

```
/* in load() */

char word[LENGTH];
FILE *fp = fopen (file, "r");

/* in getWord () */

  if (noofchar >= LENGTH)
  {
      fprintf(stderr,"\nbuffer memory overflow in getWord");
      break;
  }
  word[noofchar++] = (char)c;
}

word[noofchar]='\0';
```

If you store exactly `LENGTH` characters, then the last line will write the terminating `0` beyond the end of the `word` buffer, and *probably* clobber `fp`, which is likely to crash your program inside `fclose()`.